# Logging in to Gmail using the native email app with Application Specific Password

Tags: email, gmail

How does one do this? My email password is 100+ characters, and to be frank I don't want to type the password in only to mess it up and do it over again. When I try adding my account and use my application specific password instead of my account password I get this "Please use your account password instead of your application-specific password". Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you're using WP 8.1)

That error message comes from Google, not your phone. Apparently the way you connect your Google account to Windows Phone was changed in 8.1 - you no longer enter your username and password directly to your phone, but instead are redirected to https://accounts.google.com and asked to authorise your phone the same way you'd authorise an app or website to have access to your Google account.

This effectively means that you no longer need an app-specific password for Windows Phone, because (as far as I can tell) your phone doesn't save the password you enter anyway (once authorised, it uses some other authentication method, probably OAuth), and google.com only lets you log in with your full account password. So yes, you're going to have to type it in, all 100+ characters.

If you want to review exactly what permissions Windows Phone has to your Google account, or revoke those permissions, go to your [Google Account Permissions page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions), Windows Phone should be listed there.

For more information about account permissions and how they work, see [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521).